# Ce que pensent les Européens

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, subordonnées

Voici une phrase que j'ai lue dans un journal français :

> Ce que pensent les Européens

Peut-on plutôt écrire :

> Ce que les Européens pensent

?

Answer (score 0):

Cela revient strictement à la même chose.

Comment: Normalement, le sujet précède le verbe.  Mais cela n'est pas les cas dans cette phrase.

Comment: @GeoffPurser Je ne sais pas personnellement lequel est normal; je vous fait part de cet ngram cependant, curieux de ce que vous en pensez. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=que+pensent+les+Europ%C3%A9ens%2Cque+les+Europ%C3%A9ens+pensent&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cque%20pensent%20les%20Europ%C3%A9ens%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cque%20les%20Europ%C3%A9ens%20pensent%3B%2Cc0